# Erro em código Python

Tags: python-3.x

Estou tentando rodar o seguinte código mas aparece sempre esse mesmo tipo de erro:

> ```
> "usage: bw2color_image.py [-h] --i I --p P --m M --c C
> bw2color_image.py: error: the following arguments are required: --i/--image images/robin_williams.jpg, --p/--prototxt model/colorization_deploy_v2.prototxt, --m/--model model/colorization_release_v2.caffemodel, --c/--points model/pts_in_hull.npy
> ```

É como se ele não encontrasse o endereço dos arquivos **.jpg**, **.npy**, **.prototxt** e **.caffemodel**. Não consigo achar o erro nesse código.

Abaixo segue o código que eu estou trabalhando.

```
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2

# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("--i",'--image images/robin_williams.jpg', type=str, required=True,
    help="D:\Colorir_Imagens")
ap.add_argument("--p","--prototxt model/colorization_deploy_v2.prototxt", type=str, required=True,
    help="D:\Colorir_Imagens")
ap.add_argument("--m","--model model/colorization_release_v2.caffemodel", type=str, required=True,
    help="D:\Colorir_Imagens")
ap.add_argument("--c","--points model/pts_in_hull.npy", type=str, required=True,
    help="D:\Colorir_Imagens")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# load our serialized black and white colorizer model and cluster
# center points from disk
print("[INFO] loading model...")
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(args["colorization_deploy_v2.prototxt"], args["colorization_release_v2.caffemodel"])
pts = np.load(args["pts_in_hull.npy"])

# add the cluster centers as 1x1 convolutions to the model
class8 = net.getLayerId("class8_ab")
conv8 = net.getLayerId("conv8_313_rh")
pts = pts.transpose().reshape(2, 313, 1, 1)
net.getLayer(class8).blobs = [pts.astype("float32")]
net.getLayer(conv8).blobs = [np.full([1, 313], 2.606, dtype="float32")]

# load the input image from disk, scale the pixel intensities to the
# range [0, 1], and then convert the image from the BGR to Lab color
# space
image = cv2.imread(args["albert_einstein.jpg"])
scaled = image.astype("float32") / 255.0
lab = cv2.cvtColor(scaled, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)

# resize the Lab image to 224x224 (the dimensions the colorization
# network accepts), split channels, extract the 'L' channel, and then
# perform mean centering
resized = cv2.resize(lab, (224, 224))
L = cv2.split(resized)[0]
L -= 50

# pass the L channel through the network which will *predict* the 'a'
# and 'b' channel values
'print("[INFO] colorizing image...")'
net.setInput(cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(L))
ab = net.forward()[0, :, :, :].transpose((1, 2, 0))

# resize the predicted 'ab' volume to the same dimensions as our
# input image
ab = cv2.resize(ab, (image.shape[1], image.shape[0]))

# grab the 'L' channel from the *original* input image (not the
# resized one) and concatenate the original 'L' channel with the
# predicted 'ab' channels
L = cv2.split(lab)[0]
colorized = np.concatenate((L[:, :, np.newaxis], ab), axis=2)

# convert the output image from the Lab color space to RGB, then
# clip any values that fall outside the range [0, 1]
colorized = cv2.cvtColor(colorized, cv2.COLOR_LAB2BGR)
colorized = np.clip(colorized, 0, 1)

# the current colorized image is represented as a floating point
# data type in the range [0, 1] -- let's convert to an unsigned
# 8-bit integer representation in the range [0, 255]
colorized = (255 * colorized).astype("uint8")

# show the original and output colorized images
cv2.imshow("Original", image)
cv2.imshow("Colorized", colorized)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Obs.: Completo mais tarde, sem tempo no momento.

---

> Não consigo achar o erro nesse código

Quando você esta definindo os argumentos, você esta tentando definir um valor padrão caso o argumento seja omitido, mas esta fazendo errado:

```
ap.add_argument("--i",'--image images/robin_williams.jpg', type=str, required=True,
    help="D:\Colorir_Imagens")
ap.add_argument("--p","--prototxt model/colorization_deploy_v2.prototxt", type=str, required=True,
    help="D:\Colorir_Imagens")
ap.add_argument("--m","--model model/colorization_release_v2.caffemodel", type=str, required=True,
    help="D:\Colorir_Imagens")
ap.add_argument("--c","--points model/pts_in_hull.npy", type=str, required=True,
    help="D:\Colorir_Imagens")
```

Para definir um valor padrão, introduza o parâmetro: `default`

```
ap.add_argument("--i",'--image', type=str, 
    default="images/robin_williams.jpg", help="D:\Colorir_Imagens")

ap.add_argument("--p","--prototxt", type=str,
    default="model/colorization_deploy_v2.prototxt", help="D:\Colorir_Imagens")

ap.add_argument("--m","--model", type=str,
    default="model/colorization_release_v2.caffemodel", help="D:\Colorir_Imagens")

ap.add_argument("--c","--points", type=str,
    default="model/pts_in_hull.npy", help="D:\Colorir_Imagens")
args = ap.parse_args()
print(args)
> Namespace(c='model/pts_in_hull.npy', i='images/robin_williams.jpg', m='model/colorization_release_v2.caffemodel', p='model/colorization_deploy_v2.prototxt')
```

> [Veja funcionando](https://tio.run/##ldLNSsQwEADge5@i5LJdaLOgN6EH0Ys3H0AIsZ22cfMzZKZqffma1B9WEGVzGBgmmY8kgwtPwV82xLo7WiBaV@MwRC51HFFHgkJj2X5n8jqOswPP9zmL1b5Idan7XunPQiWaxoh6l6LTI@zqkheEljjWZVGm1cOgZ8ut2Op0iOHRePVirDXakXzCUdTlBBZbcXv1cBNsiCaqu7zZk/gdRFHnGAMHfmVxYv4kXejBHrqt55tmE7zqAW1Y1POFPDl@Ju82fmt@lh3BgibIeKeHAb46nMl3H7cPxjP95yOTSs89zdZKj8vfWD5fJInyBKDcJiDLlP4dY@KqnOzX9R0)

note que foi removido o parâmetro `required` pois se estiver definido como `True` irá exigir o argumento e retornar o erro semelhante este:

```
> error: the following arguments are required: --i/--image, --p/--prototxt, --m/--model, --c/--points
```

> [Veja funcionando](https://tio.run/##pZJPS8QwEMXv/RQll@1C2wW9CT2IXrx58CiU2Ey70TQZZ6Zq/fI1qX9YQZBlcxh4vGTej8ngLPvgzysW3T05YF4WO2IgyTUNqIkh05g3P6q@pGEawcttUlRss@jX2phWfxmFqiqryk2sox5gU@YyIzQsVOZZHo@BXk9OGrX6vKPwYH37ap2zeuT6EQdV5ntw2Kjri/ur4AJZam/SZc/RInieLIFp7miCv/NRlalSkCBvog4QfhOMwYDbdWvEuxYbfGsAXZjbl7P64PlpNONKs2YdhULgQDMklk73PXx3OI2m@5xNsF74PxwUbuPf7Cfnao/zUdmpXRaDOW0P1uv2JBCOO4MU04sktsvyAQ)

outro ponto importante, é que se for informado o argumento sem valor irá retornar o erro semelhante este:

```
python program.py --i
> error: argument --i/--image: expected one argument
```

> [Veja funcionando](https://tio.run/##lZLNSsUwEIX3fYqSze2FNhd0J3QhunHnAwghttM23vwMmalaX74m9YcriHKzGDiczPlIZnDhKfjLhlh3RwtE62ochsiljiPqSFBoLNtvJa/jODvwfJ9VrPZF8qXue6U/jUo0jRH1LlWnR9jVJS8ILXGsy6JMp4dBz5Zbsfl0iOHRePVirDXakXzCUdTlBBZbcXv1cBNsiCaqu3zZk/gdiKLONQYO/MrihPkT6UIP9tBtmW@aTfCqB7RhUc8X8qT9TLzb8Fv4WewIFjRBhnd6GOAr4Ux89/H6YDzTf3xkUum7p9la6XH5G5b7i0SivAEotw3IZEpzx5hwVRb7dV3TtN8B)

#### Referência:

- [argparse — Parser for command-line options, arguments and sub-commands](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-add-argument-method)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Ajudou bastante. Tenha um ótimo fds.

Answer (score -3):

O problema que você está enfrentando é relacionado à forma como você está passando os argumentos de linha de comando usando o argparse. No código atual, você está usando add_argument de uma maneira que não está correta para os seus argumentos de caminho de arquivo.

Aqui está a correção para a parte de argumentos:

import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2

## construct the argument parser and parse the arguments

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("--i", "--image", type=str, required=True,
help="caminho para a imagem de entrada")
ap.add_argument("--p", "--prototxt", type=str, required=True,
help="caminho para o arquivo prototxt")
ap.add_argument("--m", "--model", type=str, required=True,
help="caminho para o arquivo de modelo caffemodel")
ap.add_argument("--c", "--points", type=str, required=True,
help="caminho para o arquivo de pontos npy")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

## load our serialized black and white colorizer model and cluster

## center points from disk

print("[INFO] loading model...")
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(args["prototxt"], args["model"])
pts = np.load(args["points"])

## add the cluster centers as 1x1 convolutions to the model

class8 = net.getLayerId("class8_ab")
conv8 = net.getLayerId("conv8_313_rh")
pts = pts.transpose().reshape(2, 313, 1, 1)
net.getLayer(class8).blobs = [pts.astype("float32")]
net.getLayer(conv8).blobs = [np.full([1, 313], 2.606, dtype="float32")]

## load the input image from disk, scale the pixel intensities to the

## range [0, 1], and then convert the image from the BGR to Lab color

## space

image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
scaled = image.astype("float32") / 255.0
lab = cv2.cvtColor(scaled, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)

## resize the Lab image to 224x224 (the dimensions the colorization

## network accepts), split channels, extract the 'L' channel, and then

## perform mean centering

resized = cv2.resize(lab, (224, 224))
L = cv2.split(resized)[0]
L -= 50

## pass the L channel through the network which will *predict* the 'a'

## and 'b' channel values

print("[INFO] colorizing image...")
net.setInput(cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(L))
ab = net.forward()[0, :, :, :].transpose((1, 2, 0))

## resize the predicted 'ab' volume to the same dimensions as our

## input image

ab = cv2.resize(ab, (image.shape[1], image.shape[0]))

## grab the 'L' channel from the *original* input image (not the

## resized one) and concatenate the original 'L' channel with the

## predicted 'ab' channels

L = cv2.split(lab)[0]
colorized = np.concatenate((L[:, :, np.newaxis], ab), axis=2)

## convert the output image from the Lab color space to RGB, then

## clip any values that fall outside the range [0, 1]

colorized = cv2.cvtColor(colorized, cv2.COLOR_LAB2BGR)
colorized = np.clip(colorized, 0, 1)

## the current colorized image is represented as a floating point

## data type in the range [0, 1] -- let's convert to an unsigned

## 8-bit integer representation in the range [0, 255]

colorized = (255 * colorized).astype("uint8")

## show the original and output colorized images

cv2.imshow("Original", image)
cv2.imshow("Colorized", colorized)
cv2.waitKey(0)